# Using form component as method parameter vs form field

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

I was wondering what the best practice is when manipulating a form's component.

I have a private method that I use to change some properties of a component. Should the component/control itself be received as a method parameter or is using the form field better? What oop principle is at stake here?

Here's an example of what I mean:

```cs
private void ChangeTextBoxText(TextBox tb, string newText)
{
    tb.Text = newText;
}
```

vs.

```cs
private void ChangeTextBoxText(string newText)
{
    this.textBox1.text = newText;
}
```

What are the advantages of receiving the component as a parameter over using the form field?

Comment: only one: you can use your `ChangeTextBoxText()` method for any `TextBox` within you form in the first sample.

Comment: I would not pass a control as parameter in a method.

Comment: The first method doesn't need `this`, that's a sign to make it `static`.

Comment: In the second example, it makes sense when you have a **public** method. This allows external classes to modify the property of an internal component without accessing it directly (this should be mandatory, IMO). The first example can be useful if you have an internal collection of controls and you want to modify the properties of one of the members of the collection, passing its current instance to the private method. The second parameter may be subject to intervention, depending on the instance of the component passed as argument (it's current value, it's Location, Tag, whatever).

Comment: @KJSR can you explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter, which the way will be used. This:

```
private void ChangeTextBoxText(TextBox tb, string newText)
{
    tb.Text = newText;
}
```

or this:

```
private void ChangeTextBoxText(string newText)
{
    this.textBox1.text = newText;
}
```